# Finding potentially problematic string concatationing code by \n

Tags: python, parsing, abstract-syntax-tree

In Python, a string can be replaced with a newline character, so I often get bugs that I can not think of. For example:

```
numbers = (
    'zero',
    'one',
    'two'
    'three',
    'four',
    'five',
)
```

To avoid this difficult problem, I want to check if there is a problem with the source code I want to commit using Git Hook before committing the source code to the repository. But since you may really want to combine strings, I want to force source code to have a comma at the end of every string, or no comma at the end of every string. For example:

```
# ok
numbers = (
    'zero'
    'one'
    'two'
    'three'
    'four'
    'five'
)
# ok
numbers = (
    'zero',
    'one',
    'two',
    'three',
    'four',
    'five',
)

# error
numbers = (
    'zero',
    'one',
    'two',
    'three',
    'four',
    'five'
)
```

So I checked with the AST module to see if AST module could detect it. As a result:

```
>>> import ast
>>> ast.dump(ast.parse("('1'\n'2')"))
"Module(body=[Expr(value=Str(s='12'))])"
```

Is there a good solution?

Comment: You are not the first to be bothered. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21546048/identifying-implicit-string-literal-concatenation for a solution using `tokenize`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Identifying implicit string literal concatenation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21546048/identifying-implicit-string-literal-concatenation)

Comment: Not exact duplicate, since that question asks for `'first' 'second'`, not `'first' \n 'second'`, and can't classify function call and tuple.

Comment: It's easy to check for a newline: just compare the tokens' line numbers. The answer in the dupe even shows how to access them. It's true that it doesn't distinguish between different list types, but that requirement wasn't in the OP and I'd argue that it is unnecessary since there is often little semantic difference between list and function call (depending in the function).

Comment: You are using tuples, perhaps using a different structure ( e.g. the square brackets(a list) or an ordered set) will give you what you want.  What you are seeing is an effect of unpacking the 6 element tuple into a 1 element variable - python has to do something with the extra 5 values and concatination was chosen as standard behaviour.

Comment: The above comment should be an answer so I made it one.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are using tuples, perhaps using a different structure ( e.g. the square brackets(a list) or an ordered set) will give you what you want. If I remember the tupling/untupling rules correctly what you are seeing is an effect of unpacking the 6 element tuple into a 1 element variable - python has to do something with the extra 5 values and concatination was chosen as standard behaviour