# Throw an error if *args is missing comma in function argument

Tags: python-3.x

I have a function with unknown length of inputs for a `*args` argument/parameter (I know I can use a list input instead but I want to know how to use `*args`). All works well but if I pass in scalar inputs without a comma separation it doesn't throw an error. I'd like to detect this circumstance and throw an error. How can I detect missing comma separator and throw an error for `*args`?

```
def my_fun(*args):
    
    return args

## Has comma
my_fun('cat', 'fish')
## ('cat', 'fish')

## Missing comma (Want to detect and throw an error)
my_fun('cat' 'fish')
## ('catfish',)

len(my_fun('cat' 'fish')) 
## 1


## Missing comma (Want to detect and throw an error)
my_fun('cat' 'fish', 'dog')
## ('catfish', 'dog')
```

Comment: That is not related to ``*args``. ``'cat' 'fish'`` is a single string in any context; this already happens during parsing, before Python has any idea what `my_fun` even is.

Comment: Note this doesn't happen for any scalar input, _only_ strings: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literal-concatenation. `my_fun(1 2, 3)` would be a syntax error.

Comment: _"this already happens during parsing "_ - you can see from e.g. `print(ast.dump(ast.parse("my_fun('cat' 'fish', 'dog')")))` -> `Module(body=[Expr(value=Call(func=Name(id='my_fun', ctx=Load()), args=[Constant(value='catfish'), Constant(value='dog')], keywords=[]))], type_ignores=[])`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Identifying implicit string literal concatenation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21546048/identifying-implicit-string-literal-concatenation)